# I am deploying a django web app with Docker on railway and getting app failed to respond. locally the app works fine and has no errors on logs

Tags: django, docker, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, railway

Here is my build logs

Performing system checks...

2023-10-22 18:47:59.212964: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered

2023-10-22 18:47:59.213026: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered

2023-10-22 18:47:59.213120: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:

?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory '/usr/src/app/static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

October 22, 2023 - 18:48:02

Django version 4.1.7, using settings 'apitutorial.settings'

Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/

Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

They look like the ones I get on my local machine, my fear then is there could be a networking issue, as a result the domain that I am clicking doesn't point to my web app.
Its a django rest app.

The page loads with app failed to respond.

Comment: Your app is attending on port 8000. What port are you trying to access? Do you redirect port 80 in some way?

Comment: I am using the provided domain link by railway but that is not responsive at all, so l feel l am not understanding the networking. The logs show no error but if try access my app using the provided domain , l get Application failed to respond

Comment: What l understand is  http://0.0.0.0:8000/ locall host, something like that, and in my local machine it works , but in the context of an app that is deployed l am not sure l understand

Comment: Could be this question related to your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34360912/deploying-django-app-with-docker-allowed-hosts?rq=2 ? Also, did you use the railways template to build your app?

Comment: Not really, I have no error at all, however l think the domain, l am assigned to is not connecting to the app. Some issue like that

Comment: Can you access http:\\YOURDOMAIN:8000 ?

Comment: tried that too, no l cant. But that sounds reasonable. I am not really versed with networking but this seems that url would work for computers in the containers network, just like when l run the program locally the url does work on my computer, however it is different since its on a server. I havent found the solution yet, But l have hope I will.

Comment: I suggest try to use the railway template for a Django app and do a simple app, and your code there, or check the code differences with your app. These environment cont on some specific configs to have all the pieces connected

Comment: I have done successful deploynments in the past, but they did not use Docker. I have to use docker on this one cause I need tf serving image for tensorflow models in the project. The app is probably working but not on the provided domain

Comment: I had a hard time finding the solution to this one, not yet there but its along the lines of using a proxy.  uWSGI and nginx also come into play, I am not clear about it yeet but the idea is 0.0.0.0.8000 allows access to the container only to computers in the same network as the container, its only for development. Totally makes sense for me so far

Comment: The last silly idea.... You didn't include how you run the docker image, but do you include the port export `-p` parameter, right? Maybe you can use that to redirect 8000 to 80 ?

Answer (score 0):

[Read documentation for railway](https://docs.railway.app/deploy/exposing-your-app). So I found a work around it, and it was $PORT issue, the documentation does have a little information. Here is what I did. in my entry.sh

```
python manage.py migrate --no-input
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD=$SUPER_USER_PASSWORD python manage.py createsuperuser --username $SUPER_USER_NAME --email $SUPER_USER_EMAIL --noinput

gunicorn investment_manager.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
**take not of --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT instead of --bind 0.0.0.0:8000**
```

Other things I did include using nginx for reverse proxy, I am not sure if that worked, cause my browser isn't showing nginx is handling the requests or I am not checking properly. Eitherways this was lowkey a trial and error thingy. I have another deployment to make, and I will not use nginx to see if that changes anything.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).